# Algorithm for sort by "active"

Tags: discussion

When viewing questions, we can sort by "newest", "votes", "active", etc. All the sort options except "active" are clear to me.  What is the algorithm used for deciding "active" sort?

Is it just that the most recently "touched" question gets bumped up, where touched could mean

1. Asking a new question
2. Posting a new answer
3. Retagging or editing the question

I've noticed that adding comments does not bump up the question.

Is this how the active sort works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing an answer also bumps a question.  See [this answer on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11596/how-is-the-hot-active-question-algorithm-implemented/11601#11601).